# How to make the content collapse by a button in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, animation

I have such a column, consisting as it were of the title and the content created via `List.generate`. How I can create an animation of collapsing this list into a title, actually by clicking on the title itself?

```
Column(
      children: [
        GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {},
          child: Container(
            color: Theme.of(context).sliderTheme.inactiveTrackColor,
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 3),
              child: Center(
                child: Text('${category.name}',
                    style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline6.copyWith(
                        fontSize: 16,
                        color: Theme.of(context).selectedRowColor)),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Column(
          children: List.generate(category.items.length, (index) {
            return Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  border: (index + 1) != category.items.length
                      ? Border(
                          bottom: BorderSide(
                              color: Style.inactiveColorDark.withOpacity(1.0),
                              width: 0.5))
                      : null),
              child: Padding(
                padding:
                    const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 12.0, horizontal: 24),
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: [
                    Row(
                      children: [
                        Container(
                          width: 12,
                          height: 12,
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              color: Color(int.parse(category.color)),
                              shape: BoxShape.circle),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          width: 12,
                        ),
                        Text('${category.items[index].description}',
                            style: Theme.of(context)
                                .primaryTextTheme
                                .headline1
                                .copyWith(fontSize: 16)),
                      ],
                    ),
                    SwitchButton(
                      isActive: category.items[index].isAdded,
                      activeColor:
                          Theme.of(context).sliderTheme.activeTrackColor,
                      inactiveColor:
                          Theme.of(context).sliderTheme.inactiveTrackColor,
                      activeCircleColor:
                          Theme.of(context).sliderTheme.activeTickMarkColor,
                      inactiveCircleColor:
                          Theme.of(context).sliderTheme.inactiveTickMarkColor,
                      turnOn: () {
                        ChosenFeeling removingElement = ChosenFeeling(
                          id: 000,
                          isAdded: false,
                        );

                        //  If chosen list is empty
                        if (chosenfeelings.isEmpty) {
                          chosenfeelings.add(ChosenFeeling(
                              isAdded: true, id: category.items[index].id));
                        } else {
                          //  If user tap on switchButton 2 times
                          chosenfeelings.removeWhere((element) {
                            if (element.id != null &&
                                element.id == category.items[index].id) {
                              removingElement = element;
                            }
                            return _isNeedToRemoveWhenOn(
                              currentItem: category.items[index],
                              listItem: element,
                            );
                          });

                          // If list isn`t empty and chosen item isn`t in list
                          if (category.items[index].id != removingElement.id) {
                            chosenfeelings.add(ChosenFeeling(
                              id: category.items[index].id,
                              isAdded: true,
                            ));
                          }
                        }
                      },
                      turnOff: () {
                        ChosenFeeling removingElement = ChosenFeeling(
                          id: 000,
                          isAdded: false,
                        );

                        if (chosenfeelings.isEmpty) {
                          chosenfeelings.add(ChosenFeeling(
                            id: category.items[index].id,
                            isAdded: false,
                          ));
                        } else {
                          //  If user tap on switchButton 2 times
                          chosenfeelings.removeWhere((element) {
                            if (element.id != null &&
                                element.id == category.items[index].id) {
                              removingElement = element;
                            }
                            return _isNeedToRemoveWhenOff(
                              currentItem: category.items[index],
                              listItem: element,
                            );
                          });
                          // If list isn`t empty and chosen item isn`t in list
                          if (category.items[index].id != removingElement.id) {
                            chosenfeelings.add(ChosenFeeling(
                              id: category.items[index].id,
                              isAdded: false,
                            ));
                          }
                        }
                      },
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            );
          }),
        )
      ],
    );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to use expandable package for this purpose:
https://pub.dev/packages/expandable

Create expandable controller outside of build method

```
final ExpandableController _expandableController = ExpandableController();
```

And then use it like this:

```
ExpandableNotifier(
controller: _expandableController,
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Expandable(
            collapsed: ExpandableButton( 
              child: titleWidget(),
            ),
            expanded: Column(  
              children: [
                ExpandableButton( 
                 child: titleWidget(),
                ),
                list(),
              ]
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
```

Don't forget to dispose controller after using it

```
@override
void dispose() {
 _expandableController.dispose();
 super.dispose();
}
```

Hope this helps. You can also create your own animation with a little research